# Moralis Error When Authenticating with Metamask

Tags: web3js, metamask

I’m following the YouTube tutorial for authenticating users with metamask but getting an error.

Code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Metamask Demo</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>                      
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/moralis/dist/moralis.js"></script>

    
</head>

<body>
    
    
    <button onclick="login()">Login with Metamask</button>

    <script>
        
        Moralis.initialize("hbLGi00XmJZOwrkmjGeYXLmPOxdgg4Bj2GyAA6Gx"); // Application id from moralis.io
        Moralis.serverURL = "https://fc7em77djryo.moralis.io:2053/server"; //Server url from moralis.io
    
        async function login(){
            console.log("login clicked");
            var user = await Moralis.Web3.authenticate();
            }
        
    
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
moralis.js:4497 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Non ethereum enabled browser
    at moralis.js:4497
    at tryCatch (moralis.js:24495)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (moralis.js:24725)
    at Generator.next (moralis.js:24550)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (moralis.js:23942)
    at _next (moralis.js:23964)
    at moralis.js:23971
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new Wrapper (moralis.js:26960)
    at moralis.js:23960
```

Tutorial Video: https://youtu.be/6BfOtYfwFBI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Moralis to work properly, you have to host your pages through a server. When you open the HTML file directly, you will face this issue.

This has been mentioned in the moralis docs for your reference over here - [Uncaught Reference error- Non Ethereum Browser](https://docs.moralis.io/misc/troubleshooting#uncaught-in-promise-error-non-ethereum-enabled-browser)

Hope this helps.